# Writing html form input to text file using python

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to use this code to print a number from a html form to a text document for storage but it doesn't seem to be working

```
@app.route("/result",methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        timer = request.form['timer_input']
        f = open("timer.txt", "w")
        f.write("Water every {} days".format(timer)
        templateData = template(text = "timer")
        return render_template('timer.html', **templateData)

<form>Set frequencys (e.g. 2 = every 2 days): <br>  
    <input type ="number" name="timer_input">
    <br> 
</form>
```

does anyone know why it's not working? I've looked at several places for alternatives but they all use cgi or php and I'm not interested in using either

Comment: Are you using flask?

Comment: Where are you seeing error messages? What specifically isn't working?

Comment: action and method attribute missing

Comment: also f.close() missing

Comment: Yeah it was the action and method part that I was missing thanks and also the request import thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your initial problem looks solved, here are several bits of suggestions:

1. It is more typical for one address (view) to display a form and another
   address to showswhat the result is when form is completed.
2. File write operation looks more secure as a separate function. You need to close the file, or better use `with`.
3. You do nothing on `GET`, so the function can be simplified.

Here is the code with these ideas in mind:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('timer.html')


@app.route("/result", methods= ['POST'])
def result():
   timer = request.form['timer_input']
   log_message = "Water every {} days".format(timer)
   screen_message = "Sure, will water every {} days!".format(timer)
   save(log_message)
   return screen_message 


def save(text, filepath='timer.txt'):
    with open("timer.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(text)
app.run()
```

**templates/timer.html**:

```
<html><body>

<form action = "result" method = "POST">
Set frequencies (e.g. 2 = every 2 days): 
<br>  
    <input type ="number" name="timer_input">
    <input type = "submit">
<br> 
</form>

</body></html>
```